# encrypt and decrypt (mysql and php)

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, query-string

I'm a newbie programmer, and got a project in which I need to encrypt a data using a mysql command. Though, the given problem is this, we need to pass the encrypted data (from mysql) to a querystring `?view=encrypted_data` and now here is the tricky part, we need to decrypt it using mysql also. Is it possible? or is their any possibility that you can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not encrypt and decrypt using PHP? PHP has many encryption possibilities and you do not want to overstress the SQL server for something better done in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: @sachleen: hah, why do you think it is?

Comment: Because you have a problem with very specific requirements and "we" need to do something probably means others have the same problem. If it's homework, you should tag it as such. We don't want to give out answers, we want to help you learn.

Comment: yes guys, this is a homework. so does it mean it won't work?

Comment: it's actually giving me a headache.

Comment: Look at the link in my answer. It has everything you need. Homework just tells us to guide you to the answer rather than giving it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the MySQL [Encryption and Compression Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html). That's as much as I can give you short of giving you an answer... Take a look at `ENCODE` and `DECODE` functions, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

use AES_ENCRYPT to encrypt and AES_DECRYPT tp decrypt it . But i dont know why you should not use php's encryption methods.

Comment: ok, just tried this, but it won't solve our homework, the AES_ENCRYPT(data, 'abc') definitely work fine! but when we check the link it has special characters on it. so we tried the AES_DECRYPT and didn't return any

Comment: can you post the encrypted string here, we will see whats going wrong , you can use any dummy text to encrypt

Comment: `code`
 mysql> select DECODE(ENCODE('data','satdev'),'satdev');
+------------------------------------------+
| DECODE(ENCODE('data','satdev'),'satdev') |
+------------------------------------------+ 
| data                                     |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
`code`